# Chrome Extension Response from Content Script is Undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a simple Chrome Extension, code below. When a button in my popup is clicked I want to copy the selected text from the users browser tab.

Problem: all the responses back from my Content Script selection.js are undefinied

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Selected Text",
  "description": "copying your highlighted text",
  "version": "0.1",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_title": "Selected Text",
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "<all_urls>"
   ],
   "content_scripts": [
    {
     "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
     "js": ["selection.js"],
     "run_at": "document_start",
     "all_frames": true
    }
   ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Selected Text</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Selected Text</h1>
    <p id="text">Not Selected</p>
    <button id="checkPage">Copy Highlighted Text!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function getSelectedText() {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getSelection"}, function(response) {
      // PROBLEM: response is always undefined
      var text = response.data;
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = text;                                              
    });
  });                
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
  checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    getSelectedText();
  }, false);
}, false);
```

selection.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.method == "getSelection")
    sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
  else
    sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

Comment: 1. The first thing to do is to [debug](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) the extension: set a breakpoint inside the content script's message listener and then step through the popup code. 2. Try replacing the deprecated `sendRequest` and `getSelected` methods with the modern `sendMessage` and `query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, ...` (see [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) API). You may also want to use the recommended `chrome.runtime` instead of `chrome.extension`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have some paid work I need to focus on but then will get back to this again and update when I have the chance

Answer (score 1):

Remember when changing your code to do BOTH:

1. Reload your extension (in the chrome://extensions page)
2. refresh the website page (i.e. Ctrl + R) that you are testing it on

It seems that the content script will only get refreshed by doing 2), while the popup would get refreshed by 1).